# Does Helix mix two genres of Vampires and Zombies?

Tags: vampire, zombie, helix

After episode 11 and 12 of Helix, I got this feeling that helix is mixing two genres of Vampires and Zombies and sugarcoat it with science.

Here is my Argument:

Vampires:

1. Dr. Hiroshi Hatake and other 500 immortals have the Silver eyes.
2. Dr. Hiroshi Hatake and other 500 Immortals have physical strength.
3. Constance Sutton is seen grinding down her teeth.
4. Some of the immortals have gothic and Medieval names like Constance.
5. Dr. Julia Walker blood could heal others very fast.
6. Dr. Sarah Jordan became Silver eyed after using Dr. Julia Walker blood.
7. Also, they have something they call the Board.

I want to say they have higher sexual drive, but It only can attributed to the Constance Sutton and The Scythe.

Zombies:

1. Dr. Peter Farragut got superhuman physical strength after infection.
2. They hunt others.
3. They have horde mind.
4. They could infect others by passing their spits aka black goo (It's like biting in other zombie stories).
5. They are ugly.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to speculate. At first I thought we were getting nanobot-zombies or at least some form of biologically-explainable zombies. But then they started sword-fighting and screaming "There can be only one!" and Clancy Brown showed up bald, and it's just a mess story-wise.

Comment: I don't think you're far off (the zombie bit, in particular, is pretty obvious) but I'm also not sure what kind of answer you can get here, since this is all speculation. Helix's writers are making up their own story, and unless/until one of them comes out and admits what their inspirations were we can only guess.

Comment: It all remains to be seen, but speculatively a lot of the evidence does point to Hatake et al being some kind of vampire. The "zombies" is a harder call - they certainly share some common characteristics with zombies as generally defined, but also display a degree of co-operative behaviour and intelligence not normally seen in traditional zombies. They remind me of the rage-infected in 28 Days Later but with more intelligence (at least in some of them e.g. Peter).

Comment: @Nathan They remind me of Ants and Bees because of their swarm intelligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to pure speculation, but for the sake of it one can look at the points. They all can of course be inspiration. To more clearly point out some of the differences and likenesses: (Yes, this could be much deeper)

#### Vampires:

1. >Dr. Hiroshi Hatake and other 500 immortals have the Silver eyes.<

   - Vampires has good night vision and some have hypnotic powers, but their eyes are rather black due to dilated pupils. The *Ilarians* have not, at least from what I recall, any advantages with their shiny eyes. The light sensitivity is somewhat vampyrish though.
2. >Dr. Hiroshi Hatake and other 500 Immortals have physical strength.<

   - But not extra/super strength. (Unless I've missed something?) Though, of course, if one train martial arts for a couple of hundred years one are likely to gain some strength and skills.
3. >Constance Sutton is seen grinding down her teeth.<

   - Weird one. Perhaps some shark or beaver genome ;)
4. >Some of the immortals have gothic and Medieval names like Constance.<

   - As they have lived for centuries it is *natural*. Constance is also still in use ...
5. >Dr. Julia Walker blood could heal others very fast.<

   - Not her blood but her spinal fluid.
6. >Dr. Sarah Jordan became Silver eyed after using Dr. Julia Walker blood.<

   - Again spinal fluid, not blood. They perform a lumbar puncture (spinal tap) on Julia and Sarah receives a cerebrospinal fluid infusion. The vectors get abdominal injection from some RNA protein magic.
7. >Also, they have something they call the Board.<

   - An organization like Ilaria is likely to have a board ... :)

... and they do not drink blood, (at least not yet), or have shown other abnormal needs when it comes to nutrition.

#### Zombies:

1. >Dr. Peter Farragut got superhuman physical strength after infection.<

   - *Normal* zombies does not have superhuman strength. Zombies are rather motivated/task oriented, does not feel pain, attack in hordes, etc. which all accumulates to *strength* in its own way, but not heightened physical strength. In Helix the vectors has heightened senses, functional cardiovascular system, and Peter even show signs of being a stalker (Picture wall of Julia in air shafts).
2. >They hunt others.<

   - As a part of an evolved virus. They do not hunt for food, but to spread the infection. Zombies wants meat and has no thought for growing in numbers. Though end-result is the same.
3. >They have horde mind.<

   - They also have a very heightened need to protect each other, unlike zombies . They also seem to have some sort of leader trough Peter.
4. >They could infect others by passing their spits aka black goo (It's like biting in other zombie stories).<

   - This is to spread the virus. Zombies bite to eat, not (consciously) to spread virus, though again: end-result is somewhat the same.
5. >They are ugly.<

   - That's rather judgmental, huh? :)

... Peter gets cured ergo he is not dead, or put another way: cured zombies?

---

The virus is somewhat like *furious rabies*. Peter seems to have hydrophobia in the opening scene. Vectors show aggression, (have a compulsion to spread the virus,) etc.

[To quote wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies#Hydrophobia):

> Hydrophobia ("fear of water"), is the historic name for Rabies. It refers to a set of symptoms in the later stages of an infection in which the victim has difficulty swallowing, shows panic when presented with liquids to drink, and can't quench its thirst. Saliva production is greatly increased, and attempts to drink, or even the intention or suggestion of drinking may cause excruciatingly painful spasms of the muscles in the throat and larynx.

Sounds familiar? (Though in this case it would be an even more extreme variant.)

As zombie virus sometimes are compared to some sort of mutated rabies this is a likeness.

---

#### All over all

Get what you mean. The zombie factor crossed my mind as well at an early stage, though not the vampire one. Then again I put it aside as there are so many other possibilities.